# Where can I find the source code for Liferay Sync?

Tags: data-request, licensing, software

[Liferay](http://liferay.com/) is an [enterprise portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_portal) software.
One of its components is [Liferay Sync](https://www.liferay.com/products/liferay-sync/features).

**QUESTION:** Where can I find the source code of Liferay Sync?

Unlike other Liferay components, it does not seem to be present at https://github.com/liferay.

Their website says "Liferay Portal is the leading open source portal for the enterprise". [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liferay) says it is LGPL-licensed AND proprietary.

Comment: I see nothing on their website claiming that the product is 'open source' or similar.  Just because they give it away doesn't mean that they give away the source code as well.  If you have reason to believe that the program uses GPL components that would require them to make their code available, then contact them and request the source code.  (they don't necessarily have to have it posted to a website).

Comment: @Joe: liferay.com says "Liferay Portal is the leading open source portal for the enterprise"

Comment: but you can release the main package as open source, and then release plugins and such as closed source.  Just because the main product is open source doesn't make all components of their ecosystem the same license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Liferay has chosen to not release the source code of the Liferay Sync client.

It is therefore not open source.

If you find new information, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a github https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins for liferay plugins. May be, it's here.

Comment: Thanks! I just searched. This contains the server-side part, but not the sync client.